# C++ Win32 SaveTextFile Method error -- error unexplained

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

I am having a bit of trouble with my *saveTextFile( )* method. Everything seems to compile well, except the compiler reports an error. It does **not** explain as to what is causing the error. I am using g++ as my compiler, and the compiler is being accessed by my NetBeans IDE. Could there be something wrong with the compiler or my code? Here is the code below:

```
void saveTextFile(HWND hwnd)
{

    GetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_MAIN_EDIT), buffer,
                  sizeof(buffer));//dont worry
    TCHAR szFilters[] = "All\0*.*\0Text\0.txt\0";
    TCHAR szFilePathName[sizeof(buffer)] = "";
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    DWORD dwWritten;
    HANDLE hf;

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = szFilters;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFilePathName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(buffer);
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    if(GetSaveFileName(&ofn) == TRUE) {
        hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,
                        CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        WriteFile(hf,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&dwWritten,0);
        CloseHandle(&hf);
    }
}
```

I checked the code from *top to bottom* and there is **no** syntax errors. The compiler still reports to me with an error. The error:

[image]

Comment: If you read the error message carefully, it is not a compiler error.  It is a linker error.  You are not linking in the library that contains the `GetSaveFileName` function.

Comment: How do I link it then? What is the library?

Comment: Isn't that part of the documentation for your environment, namely how to link to external libraries?  I have not used Netbeans for this, but somewhere is an option to add a library to link to.  Look at the documentation for this function, and the `Library` section. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Most likely the library is named `libcommdlg32.a` or similar.

Comment: IIRC, g++ for Windows is able to read the export table of DLLs directly, without needing a separate import library.  So one would need to add `Comdlg32.dll` to the link command

Comment: Where would I find the library?

Comment: you need to link to `Comdlg32.dll`.

Comment: Yes, but where is that, exactly, in the windows folders?

Comment: *comdlg32.dll* resides in `%SystemRoot%\system32` (or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` for a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit OS), like all other system modules.